# How to balance the cassandra cluster while node is DOWN

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

Our cluster is unbalanced and most of the data is in one node. Now the node which as most of the data is dead because of out of space.

How to bring the node UP with ready only mode and rebalance the cluster?

We are using vnodes and DSE 4.0.3

Comment: What error are you seeing on the dead node? What about being out of space is causing it to die?

Comment: What is your replication factor and cluster size? Do you know why the cluster became unbalanced in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit read only mode for Cassandra.  As such you're likely to need to temporarily add some disk space to the node to get it online and then rebalance the cluster.

If that's not an option then removing snapshots can sometimes give you enough space to get going.  Running nodetool cleanup can also help if it's not previously been run.

If you're using vnodes - then a common problem is if you've converted an old style token node to vnodes.  The node will just grab an even range of tokens that maps to it's original range.  If the other nodes in the cluster have randomly generated tokens it'll lead to a huge imbalance between them.  Decommissioning the node and then re-adding it should resolve the problem.

The output of nodetool ring will show us if that's happened.  Actually the chances are a decom and re-add will be the solution in any case.

Comment: nodetool drain will stop accepting writes and flush all column families. Node will still remain up.

Answer (score 0):

Use `nodetool drain` to stop receiving writes on a certain node.